# Javascript textbox onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, phone-number

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="phone" " runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.EditPhone()"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 String.prototype.EditPhone= function () {

 var str = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        if (str.substring(0, 1) == "0") // If first value is "0" remove it
            str = str.substring(1, str.length);

        return str;
    };
```

I remove if first string value is **"0"**.

After that I enter phone number **5552221133** etc..

If i change **11** to 44 i can not **remove/change 11** and write new value(44) because of onkeyup value.

If i return null it is not working again.
How can i remove/change text according to my code ?

Comment: what did you want to do in a keyup event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have

```
<asp:TextBox ID="phone" " runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.EditPhone()"></asp:TextBox>
```